# error: cannot find symbol method findFirstVisibleItemPosition()

Tags: android

I think my code is ok, but for some reason I have this error. This is my code:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)
        {
            if(dy > 0) //check for scroll down
            {
                visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                pastVisiblesItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                if (loading)
                {
                    if ( (visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount)
                    {
                        loading = false;
                        Log.v("...", "Last Item Wow !");
                        //Do pagination.. i.e. fetch new data
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I have already imported android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager and decleared

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
```

Answer (score 4):

Because there is no method like `findFirstVisibleItemPosition` in `RecyclerView.LayoutManager` (See [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html)). You need to use [LinearLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html) to use [findFirstVisibleItemPosition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#findFirstVisibleItemPosition())

Change your declaration from this

```
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager
```

to this

```
private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager
```

Comment: Or a `GridLayoutManager` (which extends `LinearLayoutManager` so no surprise) or a `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`. Basically it is a standard method on all implementations provided by the support lib, but it is not on the base class.

Comment: @MarcinKoziński No because only `LinearLayoutManager` has `findFirstVisibleItemPosition` method and `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` has `findFirstVisibleItemPositions` which returns int array. So this is why it is not in base class.

Comment: You are right, sorry. I didn't notice that staggered grids is a little different. But grid is just a subclass of linear, so it should have it as well.

Comment: @MarcinKoziński Yes you are absolutely right. `GridLayoutManager` will have that method too!

Comment: So what functiom do I have to use in with RecycleView.LinearLayout?

Comment: @AlessandroLosavio What function? You only have to change the declaration as mentioned in the answer. Rest is fine I think!