# findFirstVisibleItemPosition Not Found In GridLayoutManager

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to access the method `findFirstVisibleItemPosition()`, however it is not found. How do I access this method?

Thanks,

Isaiah Thompson

```
grid.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
            //totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            int t =mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();//NOT FOUND
            int h = mLayoutManager.getWidth();
            totalItemCount = recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount();


            if (visibleItemCount>=(int) (totalItemCount/2)) {
                System.out.println("h");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37468446/6819340

Comment: Yes it does! Thank you DarShan